# No input prompt

Tags: python, python-3.5

Why am I getting no prompt for input when I run this in IDE 3.5

```
#Main function - discovered in parts from Felicia London
def main():
# get the celsius input to convert
    F1,F2 = eval(input("Enter range for celsius\n"))
#print the table header print("Celsius\tFahrenheit")
    print("Celsius\tFahrenheit")
#print the table header print("Celsius\tFahrenheit")
#invoke the c to f function celsiusToFahrenheit(fl,f2)
#get the fahrenheit input to convert
    Gl,G2 = eval(input("Enter range for fahrenheit temp"))
#print the table header print("Farenheit\tCelcius")
    print("Fahrenheit\tCelsius")
```

Comment: Do you call main() anywhere?

Comment: `eval` is very "bad" practice... try not to use it if you can

Comment: Let me re-emphasize @shahaf's comment. `eval` is ***very bad*** practice, and is quite dangerous. ***Do not use it***.

Answer (score 1):

Your **main()** method needs to be invoked for you to see the prompt .. try calling it at the end of your program to see if it does it.

`main()`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't called `main`. I'm assuming your used to a language like `C` were you define a main function and put your code in there, however it isn't like that in Python. You just put your code straight in. If you need to use the function then you can call it by using `main()`.

So you can use this:

```
F1,F2 = eval(input("Enter range for celsius\n"))
print("Celsius\tFahrenheit")
print("Celsius\tFahrenheit")
print("Celsius\tFahrenheit")
celsiusToFahrenheit(fl,f2)
Gl,G2 = eval(input("Enter range for fahrenheit temp"))
print("Farenheit\tCelcius")
print("Fahrenheit\tCelsius")
```

Or this:

```
def main()
    F1,F2 = eval(input("Enter range for celsius\n"))
    print("Celsius\tFahrenheit")
    print("Celsius\tFahrenheit")
    print("Celsius\tFahrenheit")
    celsiusToFahrenheit(fl,f2)
    Gl,G2 = eval(input("Enter range for fahrenheit temp"))
    print("Farenheit\tCelcius")
    print("Fahrenheit\tCelsius")
main()
```